# npm command not found when running node app from bash script (linux EC2)

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, amazon-ec2, systemd

I have a node app on an linux AMI EC2 instance, and I want to run it with systemd. I've written a bash script with the npm start command, but when I run it with systemd the logs tell me that the npm command cannot be found:

```
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Started NodeApp.
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Starting NodeApp...
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal start.sh[9609]: /home/ec2-user/source/NodeApp/start.sh: line 8: npm: command not found
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal systemd[1]: NodeApp.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit NodeApp.service entered failed state.
Nov 03 21:22:45 ip-10-85-147-43.ec2.internal systemd[1]: NodeApp.service failed.
```

When I run npm -v it shows 7.4.0.

here's my bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

cd home/ec2-user/source/NodeApp/
npm start
```

And the contents of NodeApp.service

```
[Unit]
Description= Node app

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/source/NodeApp/start.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What is the reason for using the shell script? Just use `WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/source/NodeApp/` and `ExecStart=/full/path/to/npm start`

Comment: @jordanm I just tried it your way and it says command not found, even when using the full path to the npm command

Answer (score 0):

Hi its easy to run node app using a process management tool called PM2, you can install PM2 directly to the Ec2 using terminal console and run the www file which is located in the soucefolder/bin

Install PM2 : `npm install pm2 -g` or `pm2 completion install`

RUN PM2 : `cd /source_folder/bin` and locate www file

```
pm2 start www --name="Application Name"
```